# Is there anyway to make this html text fit mobile screen and break line automatically?

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to make this html text fit mobile screen and break line automatically? As you can see in the screenshot, there is an horizantal scroll.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjD33.png) Here is my code:

```
<div class="code">
<xmp>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Current Text</p>

<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New 
Text"'>Click To Change Text</button>

</body>
</html>
</xmp>
</div>
```

This is the css of the text box:

```
.code { 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
line-height: 16px; 
overflow: auto; 
width: 100%; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
.code:hover { background-repeat:no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`XMP` is obsolete, use `PRE` or `CODE` - I would go with the `CODE` element in your case.
https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/NonStandard.html

You can use CSS word-break property.

```
.code { 
word-break: break-all;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
line-height: 16px; 
overflow: auto; 
width: 100%; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
.code:hover { background-repeat:no-repeat; }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp